# From pandas array without duplicates to another data structure?

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe and it has ~ 10k column values.
I want to get an array without duplicates, but also have properties such as lookup by index + it's sorted!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path',sep=';')
arr = []
for i in df[0].values:
    if i not in arr:
        d.append(i)
```

it actually is very time/memory consuming because of the iteration through 10k element array, then looking up if element is not already stored in a newly created array and afterwards appending an element if conditions are matched.
I know set has a properties such as there can not be duplicates, but I can not look up element easily by index + it can not be sorted.
May be there is another possible solution to it ?

Comment: Try: `np.unique(df[0])` or `df[0].unique()`

Comment: @AntonvBR this is indeed a great solution!
Can you post it in comments section I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for np.unique:

```
np.unique(df[0])
```

Or adapted in pandas as [.unique()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
df[0].unique()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates for more information [drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: Technically they are not duplicates i would like to remove from pandas,
the other values in a row have some important value, tho i just want to get the column values w/ duplicates

Comment: If you have any example like what you have and what is your desired output, that would be easier to understand the problem